# Array of components not rerendering when new ones added - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import StartMultiple from './Start.multiple.js';

export default class Start extends Component {
    constructor()
    {   
        super();
        this.state = {count: 4}; 
        this.count = 4;
        this.repeats = [ 
            <StartMultiple key="1"/>,
            <StartMultiple key="2"/>,
            <StartMultiple key="3"/>
        ];  

    }   

    add_repeat(e)
    {   
        this.repeats.push(<StartMultiple key={this.count}/>);
        this.count = this.count + 1;
        console.log(this.repeats);
    }   

    render()
    {   
        var count = 1;

        return(
            <div>
                {this.repeats}

                <button onClick={ () => this.add_repeat(event)}>clickable</button>
            </div>
        );  
    }   
}
```

However, whenever I press the button, the component is definitely added in (as shown from the console.log) however the dom does not rerender the new ones. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are not setting the state in your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are not using state.. Instead you are creating your own variable...

Put repeates variable inside state.. and use this.setState to set new values

Comment: Didn't realise I needed to use setState. I thought it was the same as assigning it using `this.state.repeats = blah`